# Shell Scripting: read input from command output

Tags: shell, scripting-language

Why does the following code gives only first line from ps -eaf output in ps.out?

```
while read line; 
do
   echo $line>ps.out; 
done < <(/bin/ps -eaf)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are truncating the file each time so you only get the last line. You probably want `>>` instead of `>`.

Comment: apologies for the dumb mistake. should have been >> Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Or redirect the entire loop output by putting ">ps.out" after the "done".